# how to deserialize XML to List<Object>

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

i try to create WCF with return value is XML. 
when i try to deserialize xml file to object, i have error.

this my code to deserialize file

my controller

```
//serialize request to wcf//    
var requestXML = Lib.Serializer.ObjectSerializer.Serialize(request);
//get response from wcf//
var XMLResult = Lib.Net.Http.Post(requestXML,"http://localhost:53721/RoomRate.svc/RoomRates", 60);
//deserialize xml file to object//
var response = Lib.Serializer.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize<List<RoomRatesResponses>>(XMLResult);
```

my class for deserialize xml

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{
    T result;
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        result = (T)ser.Deserialize(tr);
    }
    return result;
}
```

my object model

```
public class RoomRatesResponses
{
    public List<RoomRateResponse> ListRoomRateResponse { get; set; }

    public RoomRatesResponses()
    {
        ListRoomRateResponse = new List<RoomRateResponse>();
    }
}

public class RoomRateResponse
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public bool OperationSuccess { get; set; }
    public int Allotment { get; set; }
    public bool Breakfast { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckInDate { get; set; }
    public bool CloseSelling { get; set; }
    public double CommissionPct { get; set; }
    public string CurrCode { get; set; }
    public bool FreeSell { get; set; }
    public int RoomRateId { get; set; }
    public string RoomType { get; set; }
    public double SingleRate { get; set; }
    public double TripleRate { get; set; }
    public double TwinDoubleRate { get; set; }
}
```

when i deserialize my xml, i have error like this

> `<ArrayOfRoomRateResult xmlns=''>` was not expected.
>        Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: `System.InvalidOperationException`: `<ArrayOfRoomRateResult xmlns=''>` was not expected.

how can i deseralize my xml file??

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfRoomRateResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RoomRateResult>
    <OperationSuccess>true</OperationSuccess>
    <ErrorMessage/>
    <RoomRateId>1170</RoomRateId>
    <RoomType>superior</RoomType>
    <RoomTypeID>150</RoomTypeID>
    <Breakfast>true</Breakfast>
    <CheckInDate>2014-01-01T00:00:00</CheckInDate>
    <CurrCode>IDR</CurrCode>
    <SingleRate>450000.0000</SingleRate>
    <TwinDoubleRate>450000.0000</TwinDoubleRate>
    <TripleRate>750000.0000</TripleRate>
    <CommissionPct>15.00</CommissionPct>
    <Allotment>25</Allotment>
    <FreeSell>true</FreeSell>
    <CloseSelling>false</CloseSelling>
    <CancellationPolicy/>
  </RoomRateResult>
  <RoomRateResult>
    <OperationSuccess>true</OperationSuccess>
    <ErrorMessage/>
    <RoomRateId>1171</RoomRateId>
    <RoomType>superior</RoomType>
    <RoomTypeID>150</RoomTypeID>
    <Breakfast>true</Breakfast>
    <CheckInDate>2014-01-02T00:00:00</CheckInDate>
    <CurrCode>IDR</CurrCode>
    <SingleRate>450000.0000</SingleRate>
    <TwinDoubleRate>450000.0000</TwinDoubleRate>
    <TripleRate>750000.0000</TripleRate>
    <CommissionPct>15.00</CommissionPct>
    <Allotment>22</Allotment>
    <FreeSell>false</FreeSell>
    <CloseSelling>false</CloseSelling>
    <CancellationPolicy/>
  </RoomRateResult>
  <RoomRateResult>
    <OperationSuccess>true</OperationSuccess>
    <ErrorMessage/>
    <RoomRateId>1177</RoomRateId>
    <RoomType>deluxe</RoomType>
    <RoomTypeID>151</RoomTypeID>
    <Breakfast>false</Breakfast>
    <CheckInDate>2014-01-01T00:00:00</CheckInDate>
    <CurrCode>IDR</CurrCode>
    <SingleRate>600000.0000</SingleRate>
    <TwinDoubleRate>600000.0000</TwinDoubleRate>
    <TripleRate>850000.0000</TripleRate>
    <CommissionPct>25.00</CommissionPct>
    <Allotment>11</Allotment>
    <FreeSell>false</FreeSell>
    <CloseSelling>false</CloseSelling>
    <CancellationPolicy>
      <Cancellation>
        <CancellationPolicyID>34</CancellationPolicyID>
        <ValidFrom>2014-01-01T00:00:00</ValidFrom>
        <ValidTo>2014-01-31T00:00:00</ValidTo>
        <ValidDays>YYYYYYY</ValidDays>
        <ChargeTypeId>1</ChargeTypeId>
        <CancellationCharge>1.0000</CancellationCharge>
        <DayBeforeCheckIn>7</DayBeforeCheckIn>
      </Cancellation>
    </CancellationPolicy>
  </RoomRateResult>
  <RoomRateResult>
    <OperationSuccess>true</OperationSuccess>
    <ErrorMessage/>
    <RoomRateId>1178</RoomRateId>
    <RoomType>deluxe</RoomType>
    <RoomTypeID>151</RoomTypeID>
    <Breakfast>false</Breakfast>
    <CheckInDate>2014-01-02T00:00:00</CheckInDate>
    <CurrCode>IDR</CurrCode>
    <SingleRate>500000.0000</SingleRate>
    <TwinDoubleRate>500000.0000</TwinDoubleRate>
    <TripleRate>750000.0000</TripleRate>
    <CommissionPct>25.00</CommissionPct>
    <Allotment>22</Allotment>
    <FreeSell>false</FreeSell>
    <CloseSelling>false</CloseSelling>
    <CancellationPolicy>
      <Cancellation>
        <CancellationPolicyID>34</CancellationPolicyID>
        <ValidFrom>2014-01-01T00:00:00</ValidFrom>
        <ValidTo>2014-01-31T00:00:00</ValidTo>
        <ValidDays>YYYYYYY</ValidDays>
        <ChargeTypeId>1</ChargeTypeId>
        <CancellationCharge>1.0000</CancellationCharge>
        <DayBeforeCheckIn>7</DayBeforeCheckIn>
      </Cancellation>
    </CancellationPolicy>
  </RoomRateResult>
</ArrayOfRoomRateResult>
```

Comment: Did you rename the class from `RoomRateResult` to `RoomRateResponse` ?

Comment: yes i did.. but, still have same error

Comment: Also the List is named incorrectly, it should be `ArrayOfRoomRateResult` rather than `ListRoomRateResponse`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a typo - probably due to testing on old file versions, and offers no future benefit to SO users.

Comment: can you give me example, which part i must rename to solve my problem? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the dummy code that you need to fix the issue. It shows how the serialization works here, reverse is to be done for De-serialization, note the class and variable name:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Code.Without.IDE
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697928/how-to-deserialize-xml-to-listobject
    public class Dummy
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            List<RoomRateResult> ArrayOfRoomRateResult = new List<RoomRateResult>();
            RoomRateResult rs1 = new RoomRateResult
                                        {
                                            ErrorMessage = string.Empty,
                                            OperationSuccess = true,
                                            Allotment = 10,
                                            Breakfast = true,
                                            CheckInDate = DateTime.Now,
                                            CloseSelling = false,
                                            CommissionPct = 3.0d,
                                            CurrCode = "USD",
                                            FreeSell = true,
                                            RoomRateId = 100,
                                            RoomType = "Mega",
                                            SingleRate = 95d,
                                            TripleRate = 150d,
                                            TwinDoubleRate = 150d
                                        };

            RoomRateResult rs2 = new RoomRateResult
                                        {
                                            ErrorMessage = string.Empty,
                                            OperationSuccess = true,
                                            Allotment = 12,
                                            Breakfast = true,
                                            CheckInDate = DateTime.Now,
                                            CloseSelling = false,
                                            CommissionPct = 2.0d,
                                            CurrCode = "USD",
                                            FreeSell = true,
                                            RoomRateId = 110,
                                            RoomType = "Mega",
                                            SingleRate = 90d,
                                            TripleRate = 140d,
                                            TwinDoubleRate = 150d
                                        };

            ArrayOfRoomRateResult.Add(rs1);
            ArrayOfRoomRateResult.Add(rs2);

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<RoomRateResult>));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("serl.xml");
            ser.Serialize(writer, ArrayOfRoomRateResult);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class RoomRateResult
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public bool OperationSuccess { get; set; }
        public int Allotment { get; set; }
        public bool Breakfast { get; set; }
        public DateTime CheckInDate { get; set; }
        public bool CloseSelling { get; set; }
        public double CommissionPct { get; set; }
        public string CurrCode { get; set; }
        public bool FreeSell { get; set; }
        public int RoomRateId { get; set; }
        public string RoomType { get; set; }
        public double SingleRate { get; set; }
        public double TripleRate { get; set; }
        public double TwinDoubleRate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Serialization gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfRoomRateResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RoomRateResult>
    <ErrorMessage />
    <OperationSuccess>true</OperationSuccess>
    <Allotment>10</Allotment>
    <Breakfast>true</Breakfast>
    <CheckInDate>2013-12-19T23:11:08.2340815-08:00</CheckInDate>
    <CloseSelling>false</CloseSelling>
    <CommissionPct>3</CommissionPct>
    <CurrCode>USD</CurrCode>
    <FreeSell>true</FreeSell>
    <RoomRateId>100</RoomRateId>
    <RoomType>Mega</RoomType>
    <SingleRate>95</SingleRate>
    <TripleRate>150</TripleRate>
    <TwinDoubleRate>150</TwinDoubleRate>
  </RoomRateResult>
  <RoomRateResult>
    <ErrorMessage />
    <OperationSuccess>true</OperationSuccess>
    <Allotment>12</Allotment>
    <Breakfast>true</Breakfast>
    <CheckInDate>2013-12-19T23:11:08.2380815-08:00</CheckInDate>
    <CloseSelling>false</CloseSelling>
    <CommissionPct>2</CommissionPct>
    <CurrCode>USD</CurrCode>
    <FreeSell>true</FreeSell>
    <RoomRateId>110</RoomRateId>
    <RoomType>Mega</RoomType>
    <SingleRate>90</SingleRate>
    <TripleRate>140</TripleRate>
    <TwinDoubleRate>150</TwinDoubleRate>
  </RoomRateResult>
</ArrayOfRoomRateResult>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rename your classes for some reason as Abhinav adviced, you may create your own list which implements **IXmlSerializable**:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ArrayOfRoomRateResult")]
public class MyList : List<RoomRateResponse>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RoomRateResponse));
        var wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        reader.Read();
        if (wasEmpty)
            return;
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            var item = (RoomRateResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            Add(item);
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RoomRateResponse));
        foreach (var val in this)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, val);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you need to add attribute to **RoomRateResponse**:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RoomRateResult")]
public class RoomRateResponse
{
    //...
}
```

Now your serialization works as expected:

```
//...
var response = Lib.Serializer.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize<MyList>(xml);
```